# what is the difference between `find .` and /home/user/* as an input to for command

Tags: shell, find, wildcards, command-substitution, for

What is the difference between `find .` and `/home/user/*` as an input to `for` command.?
For example:

```sh
for var in $(find .)
do echo "$var"
done
```

or

```
for var in /home/user/*
do
echo "$var"
done
```

In the first case `for` command breaks up the file with names containing spaces. While in the second case it does not.
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is standard practice for shells. The order of operations is command substitution (`$(find .)`), then word splitting, then glob expansion (`/home/user/*`).

From the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) (word splitting = field splitting; glob expansion = pathname expansion):

> The order of word expansion shall be as follows:
>
> 1. Tilde expansion (see Tilde Expansion), parameter expansion (see Parameter Expansion), command substitution (see Command Substitution), and arithmetic expansion (see Arithmetic Expansion) shall be performed, beginning to end. See item 5 in Token Recognition.
> 2. Field splitting (see Field Splitting) shall be performed on the portions of the fields generated by step 1, unless IFS is null.
> 3. Pathname expansion (see Pathname Expansion) shall be performed, unless set -f is in effect.
> 4. Quote removal (see Quote Removal) shall always be performed last.

---

For this reason, it is always recommended to use globs where possible, so that word splitting does not interfere with your file names. The `$(find)` construct is actually an example of [Bash Pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: if I write `cat *`, if there exist only one file named 'abc def.txt', then it will take this as two different files. this contradicts your answer..

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Can you provide more information? `*` should match a file named `abc def.txt`. If it doesn't something is wrong so tell *exactly* what you type and *exactly* what output you get.

Comment: goto this link: http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html it says that not to use '*'

Comment: @edwardtorvalds For the problem pointed out by the Wheeler link, use `./*` and the problem is solved. The wheeler link is irrelevant to your first comment about `abc def.txt` though. I still do not know what you were trying to say with your comment about `abc def.txt`.

Comment: sorry to confuse you, I understood the concept and my doubts are clear. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

The shell does things in order.  `$(find .)` is called command substitution.  The results of command substitution are subjected:

1. word splitting,
2. pathname expansion
3. quote removal

Word splitting is what causes the problem when there are file names with spaces.

`/home/user/*` is pathname expansion.  Note that that is second to last on the above list.  It is subjected only to quote removal.

Answer (score 1):

One additional difference between the two is that shell globs (like `/home/user/*`) don't usually include "hidden files" (filenames that begin with a dot). On the other hand, `find` will match all filenames except the special directories '.' and '..' (current and parent directory).

Comment: Furthermore, that `find` command will recurse (as far as it can) - the wildcard will match only items immediately in the given directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach of explaining it: When `*` is used then the shell knows what the single elements are. The `find` output is just a long string. The shell does not know what the elements (and their separators) are.

Command substitution can be used in a special way with a program that produces quoted output; then the problem would not appear. But in order to make the shell recognize the quoting you need e.g. `eval` which often makes the whole expression more complicated:

```
eval for var in $(ls --quoting-style=shell)\; do echo '"$var"'\; done
```

Comment: `ls --quoting-style=shell` would not help. Only literal quotes are actually treated as quotes. Any quote characters that happen to result from expansions are not special. You would have to use `eval` to get the shell to reparse expanded output, and I would not really recommend that.

Comment: Never post without trying...